# Where does the last value and blank date come from?

Tags: pivot-table, powerpivot, pivot-chart

I have encountered a strange thing in my power pivot table and chart. I have the EUR/SEK in a table and chart and as you can see here

[image]

the last value is above 70 and the date is blank-blank-blank. I have obviously checked my table and there is no blank row or value above 10.3.

Do anyone know why I have this strange value and blank date?

Best regards

Comment: how is your question related to DAX?

Comment: Using a SUM-function but maybe it isn't a necessary tag, will remove it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so this one was stupid simple. I thought I had checked everything that could go wrong but I hadn't. So the problem was all the time that my dynamic calendar hadn't update correctly and so there was values for like 7 days or so that didn't have matching dates in the calendar. These 7 or so values accumulated under blank and therefore gave me the strange chart.